# Can't update Gemfile

Tags: ruby, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I am upgrading my Heroku hosted ROR app from Ruby 1.9.3 to 2.3.1p112

I get this error on Heroku console

```
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !     Detected a mismatch between your Ruby version installed and
remote:  !     Ruby version specified in Gemfile or Gemfile.lock. You can
remote:  !     correct this by running:
remote:  !     
remote:  !     $ bundle update --ruby
remote:  !     $ git add Gemfile.lock
remote:  !     $ git commit -m "update ruby version"
remote:  !     
remote:  !     If this does not solve the issue please see this documentation:
remote:  !     
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions#your-ruby-version-is-x-but-your-gemfile-specified-y
```

So I did this and I am not sure how to fix it? Where is 2.3.1 set? If I set my Gemfile to 2.3.1 instead of 2.3.1p112 then Pushing to Heroku fails and it gives me the above error?

```
 MacBook-Pro-2:treesy-api me$ bundle platform --ruby
ruby 2.3.1p112
MacBook-Pro-2:treesy-api me$ bundler -v
Bundler version 1.17.1
MacBook-Pro-2:treesy-api me$ cat Gemfile.lock | grep -A 2 RUBY
RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.3.1p112

MacBook-Pro-2:treesy-api me$ bundle update --ruby
Your Ruby version is 2.3.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.1p112
MacBook-Pro-2:treesy-api me$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin17]s
```

Comment: To my knowledge, you usually dont need to specify the patch version anywhere. If you have any version of 2.3.1 installed on your computer, your Gemfile should say `ruby "2.3.1"`, then run `bundle` locally, see if everything works properly. Then it should also work on Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
ruby '~> 2.5.1'
```

in your `Gemfile` and

```
2.5.1
```

in your `.ruby-version`